# IntelliJ IDEA plugin for recent projects with search

Tags: intellij-idea

Everyday I work with a lot of different projects in IntelliJ IDEA.

When I click on `File -> Open Recent` I see a long long list of projects that I worked on.

Is there any plugin or solution that allows me quickly search and find relevant project?

Comment: Sounds interesting question .I thought of asking .

Comment: @soorapadman I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yeah thanks for the answer. let me try .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `File` | `Open Recent` | **Manage Projects ...**, start typing the name for the quick search/filter.
- `Help` | `Find Action` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), **Manage Projects**, start typing the project name.
- [Related usability issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205462) for the **Manage Projects** menu being at the bottom of the list and hard to select/discover.

Note that you can customize **Menus and Toolbars** to make **Manage Projects** item at the top of the **Open Recent** list:

[image: manage]

Or add a copy of this action where you want, even at the top of the `File` menu:

[image: manage copy]

Or add a direct shortcut to open the **Manage Projects** dialog in the IDE **Keymap** settings:

[image: keymap]

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed!